# How to get node values from each tree in a random forest?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am generating a random forest for multi-output regression problem. At the end, predict method gives me results which is average of all the different results generated by different trees in the forest for a given x. What I am looking for all the 'ys' generated by those tress in a numpy format(may be)? I am not sure if there is any method available in scikit-learn's `RandomForestRegressor`.

This is how my tree looks like:
[image]

```
estimator = model2.estimators_[23][9]
from sklearn.externals.six import StringIO  
from IPython.display import Image  
from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz
import pydotplus
dot_data = StringIO()
export_graphviz(estimator, out_file=dot_data,  
                filled=True, rounded=True,
                special_characters=True)
graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue())  
Image(graph.create_png())
```

I am expecting

> [2,3,3]

but I am getting is

> 2.6

Comment: I am not sure how to upload a picture.

Comment: [How to upload images](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)